# Purely Algebraic Solution to a complex number problem

Tags: complex-numbers

> Question -  Let $z_1 , z_2 ,z_3 $ be 3 complex numbers satisfying
> $|z|=1$ and $$4z_3=3(z_1+z_2)$$ Then find the value of $|z_1-z_2|$.

Looking at the question i could  immediately see a geometric solution that we can just rearrange the equation like
$$\dfrac{2}{3}z_3=\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{2}$$
Now midpoint of $Z_1Z_2$ divides $OZ_3$ in the ration $2/3$ ($O$ is origin $Z_i$ is the respective vertex).. Using this fact we get answer as $\boxed{\dfrac{2\sqrt{5}}{3}}$

I was wondering if there was any purely algebraic solution to this? I couldnt find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left(\frac43\right)^2=|z_1+z_2|^2=2+2\Re(z_1\bar z_2)$$
hence
$$|z_1-z_2|^2=2-2\Re(z_1\bar z_2)=4-\left(\frac43\right)^2=\frac{20}9.$$

Comment: +1 That was quite simple yet good solution. Thanks!